# Morphism of algebraic groups defined over real points

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties

I am starting to study algebraic groups and I came across the following statement: let $S=\mathrm{Res}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}})$ be the restriction of scalars of the multiplicative group over $\mathbb{C}$. Then, there is a canonical map $w:\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}}\to S$ which on real points is defined as the inclusion of $\mathbb{R}^\ast$ in $\mathbb{C}^\ast$.

I don’t understand how can we obtain a map of schemes/varieties by just defining it over the set of real points. Moreover, since $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed, the set of real points doesn’t necessarily equals the whole set of points of the underlying topological space and I can’t seem to understand how an extension to the whole space can be obtained.

I am not really experienced about these topics, so if you could provide some sort of reference to learn about it (and to get more comfortable working with these kind of statements), that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure of the definitions but if $\mathbb{G_{m,R}} = V(xy-1) \subset \mathbb{A_R^2},\mathbb{G_{m,C}} = V(UW-1) \subset \mathbb{A_C^2}$, $\mathbb{Res_{C/R}G_{m,C}} = V(\Re((u+iv)(w+iz))=1,\Im((u+iv)(w+iz))=0) = V(uw-vz-1,uz+vw)\subset \mathbb{A_R^4}$ then I'd look at $(x,y) \in \mathbb{G_{m,R}} \mapsto (u,v,w,z)=(x,0,y,0) \in \mathbb{Res_{C/R}G_{m,C}}$

Comment: As you say, one doesn't obtain a map of schemes by just defining it over the set of real points, but that's not what your statement says either. The statement says that there is a *morphism of schemes* $w \colon \mathbb{G}_{m, \mathbb{R}} \to S$ *such that* the map on real points $\mathbb{G}_{m, \mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}) \to S(\mathbb{R})$ is the inclusion of $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ into $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. If I have time, I'll write something below on how one defines $w$, and why it is the claimed morphism.

Comment: A morphism of schemes is determined by functorial maps between the set of $X$-points, for every scheme $X$ (over some base, here over $\Bbb R$). So your $w : \Bbb G_m \to S$ is given by a functorial collection of group morphisms $$w_X : O_X(X)^{\times} \to S(X) = (O_X(X) \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C)^{\times}$$ for every $\Bbb R$-scheme $X$.

Comment: @Watson  thank you, that helped me a lot. Just one question: how does one know that $S(X)=(O_X(X)\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C})^\times$?

Comment: Because by definition, one has Res$_{Y/T} G : X \mapsto G(Y \times_T X)$, and $\Bbb G_m(Z) = O_Z(Z)^{\times}$. So at least we have $S(X) = O_Z(Z)^{\times}$ where $Z = X \times_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$. When $X$ is affine (which is sufficient to consider), we clearly have $S(X) = (O_X(X) \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C)^{\times}$ as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to get this off the unanswered list.

Yes, it's not true that the functor from linear algebraic groups (or even reductive groups) over $\mathbb{R}$ to real Lie groups is full. For example, let $U(1)$ denote the algebraic group given by

$$U(1)=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1))$$

with the obvious multiplication (one can think of this as the norm $1$ elements of $\mathsf{Res}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}$ if you'd like). Then, $U(1)(\mathbb{R})\cong S^1$ as real Lie groups. Note then that the map

$$\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}},U(1))\to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}),U(1)(\mathbb{R}))=\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^\times,S^1)$$

is not surjective. Indeed, every map $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}}\to U(1)$ is constant since the former is a split torus and the latter is an $\mathbb{R}$-anisotropic torus. That said, there is certainly a map of Lie groups

$$\mathbb{R}^\times\cong \mathbb{R}^{>0}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}^{>0}\cong \mathbb{R}\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong S^1$$

or more explicitly

$$x\mapsto \exp(2\pi i\log(|x|))$$

**NB:** This fully-faithfulness, and in fact *equivalence*, for $\mathbb{R}$-anisotropic groups to compact Lie groups *is* true. For example, see [Con, Theorem D.2.4].

That said, the map

$$\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}^\times\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times=(\mathsf{Res}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}})(\mathbb{R})$$

can be made functorial, and thus algebraic. Namely, for every $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $R$ one has an inclusion of $R$-algebras

$$R\hookrightarrow R\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$$

and thus an inclusion of groups

$$\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}}(R)=R^\times\hookrightarrow (R\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C})^\times=(\mathsf{Res}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}})(R)$$

Explicitly, one can model

$$\mathsf{Res}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{pmatrix}\right\}\subseteq \text{GL}_{2,\mathbb{R}}$$

and the map $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}}\to\text{GL}_{2,\mathbb{R}}$ is just the inclusion of the center of $\text{GL}_{2,\mathbb{R}}$ (the diagonal matrices).

[Con] Conrad, B., 2014. Reductive group schemes. Autour des schémas en groupes, 1, pp.93-444.